# Problem with qt + mysql interaction

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

Now I'm working on Qt project and I need some MySQL support. MySQL was installed on virtual machine (Virtual Box) on Ubuntu Server. Here's what I do:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QSqlDatabase hospital_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    hospital_db.setHostName("192.168.56.10");
    hospital_db.setDatabaseName("hospital_db");
    hospital_db.setUserName("usr1");
    hospital_db.setPassword("123");
    if(!hospital_db.open()) {
        qDebug() << "\nFailed connect to MySQL";
    };

    QTableView *tView = new QTableView;
    QSqlTableModel model;

    model.setTable("my_table");
    model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
    if (!model.select()) {
         QMessageBox msgBox;
         QString err(model.lastError().text());
         msgBox.setText(err);
         msgBox.exec();
    }
    model.setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("ID"));
    model.setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Name"));
    model.setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Address"));
    model.setHeaderData(3, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Phone"));

    tView->setModel(&model);
    tView->show();

    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("my_table");
    return app.exec();
}
```

I get "Unable to find table my_table" error . Table my_table is created properly. Here is result of `SHOW FIELDS OF my_table`:

```
+----------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| hosp_id        | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| hosp_name      | char(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| hosp_address   | char(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| hosp_ph_number | char(8)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And finally here is general_log from MySQL:

```
| 2011-08-11 12:21:54 | usr1[usr1] @  [192.168.56.1] |        36 |         0 | Connect      | usr1@192.168.56.1 on hospital_db    |
| 2011-08-11 12:21:54 | usr1[usr1] @  [192.168.56.1] |        36 |         0 | Init DB      | hospital_db                         |
| 2011-08-11 12:21:54 | usr1[usr1] @  [192.168.56.1] |        36 |         0 | Query        | SET NAMES utf8                      |
| 2011-08-11 12:21:54 | usr1[usr1] @  [192.168.56.1] |        36 |         0 | Field List   | my_table                            |
| 2011-08-11 12:21:54 | usr1[usr1] @  [192.168.56.1] |        36 |         0 | Field List   | my_table                            |
| 2011-08-11 12:21:54 | usr1[usr1] @  [192.168.56.1] |        36 |         0 | Query        | show index from my_table                |
| 2011-08-11 12:22:01 | usr1[usr1] @  [192.168.56.1] |        36 |         0 | Quit         |                                     |
```

So, What am I doing wrong?

Comment: shouldnt "QSqlTableModel model" be linked to hospital_db somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seems that I had some problems with permissions on server side. Now everything is fine.

Comment: This is what I would have guessed. You needed to grant permissions to non-local connections, didn't you?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing

```
model.setTable("mytable");
```

but according to your SQL the table name is "my_table". They are different !